# Can My Employer Track Incognito Searches on My Own Laptop When Logged into Their VPN?

Tags: vpn

So I'm freaking out a little bit. I logged into my work computer through the company VPN to check in on a project. I ran a script and I was tooling around outside of the remote desktop on my own browser. I had an incognito window open and did a search for a NSFW site. The search came up empty. I thought "that's weird" and entered in a URL. I got a "not safe to advance" alert and then I realized what was happening. All of my traffic was now going through the work VPN. I logged off immediately.

I know incognito searches don't protect me from higher level admins from viewing my browsing history. My question is, will they think I made these searches from my work computer, or will the IT people be able to see what happened? I just started this job a month ago, so I'm a little worried.

Comment: If it's traffic that's been routed through their equipment, they can see it.  They may or may not care enough to track it down (that depends on your employer), however they should be able to see the MAC address it sourced from, and know that it sourced from your equipment (personal or otherwise).  I don't think this is really the right place for this question, however, which is why i'm leaving this as a comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming it got flagged because it was obviously blocked by a firewall and sent up a warning.

Comment: Kinda depends on how they have their firewall configured.  From personal experience, I haven't actually worked at an employer that's actively emailed out alerts based on blocked traffic.  I'm not saying that's the case where you are, but it's entirely possible that they may not know the wiser, unless someone says something to them.  Ultimately the only people that would REALLY know a definitive yes/no to this are your IT department.

Comment: OK. Since I didn't actually view any NFSW sites, I should probably be OK. I might tell my boss about it (as embarrassing as it is) just to cover both of our asses if IT does bring it up.